# SQL Server: Error converting data type varchar to float with Comma as Decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I stored the values in W10Pro and the decimal values (varchar(50)) cannot be casted to float, I doubt the comma cannot be separated such that commands

```
SELECT CAST('27,18' as float) 

SELECT CONVERT(float, '27,18')
```

fire an error `Error converting data type varchar to float`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use decimal point instead of comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fiddle with internationalization settings, but the easiest way is replace, in my opinion:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('27,18', ',', '.') as float)
```